# How I can refine the proof of $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{(x,y)\, \to \,(3, - 1)} \left( {{x^2} + {y^2} - 4x + 2y} \right) = - \,4$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

To prove that $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{(x,y)\, \to \,(3, - 1)} \left( {{x^2} + {y^2} - 4x + 2y} \right) =  - \,4$$  I followed the following process:

Because the hypothesis and the definition of limit, we have:
$\sqrt {{{(x - 3)}^2} + {{(y + 1)}^2}}  < \delta \,\,\,;\,\,\,\,\left| {x - 3} \right| < \delta \,\,;\,\,\,\left| {y + 1} \right| < \delta $

Then I have to find an upper bound of:
$\left| {{x^2} + {y^2} - 4x + 2y + 4} \right|$, I complete square like this:

$\begin{array}{c}
\left| {{x^2} + {y^2} - 4x + 2y + 4} \right| = \left| {{x^2} - 6x + 9 + {y^2} + 2y + 1 + 2x - 6} \right|\\
 = \left| {{{(x - 3)}^2} + {{(y + 1)}^2} + 2(x - 3)} \right|
\end{array}$

then using the triangle inequality and relate delta epsilon:

$\begin{array}{c}
\left| {{{(x - 3)}^2} + {{(y + 1)}^2} + 2(x - 3)} \right| \le \left| {{{(x - 3)}^2} + {{(y + 1)}^2}} \right| + 2\left| {x - 3} \right|\\
 < {\delta ^2} + 2\delta \\
 = {(\delta  + 1)^2} - 1\\
 < {(\delta  + 1)^2} = \varepsilon 
\end{array}$

but the latter involves that: $\delta  = \sqrt \varepsilon-1$

and **this is consistent for $\epsilon>1$, and not for $\epsilon$ as small as desired**

So **how I can refine this demonstration?** because every time I find more disconcerting.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you are looking for, but I would define $x=3+h$ and $y=-1+k$ as $h$ and $k$ tend to $0$. then I would define $h=rcos\theta$ and $k=rsin\theta$ as $r$ tends to $0$.

Comment: @OriaGruber Thanks, but I need to make the demonstration by delta-epsilon definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your last step, you want that: $\delta^2 + 2\delta < \epsilon$, but this means $(\delta + 1)^2 < 1 + \epsilon$, and taking square root $\delta + 1 < \sqrt{1 + \epsilon}$, so $\delta < -1 + \sqrt{1 + \epsilon}$. You can take $\delta = \dfrac{-1 + \sqrt{1 + \epsilon}}{2}$, and it does the job.

Comment: Yes thanks. It's just what I needed. :)